# Do something when user cancels refresh

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In my vue.js app, I have onbeforeunload listener and if user changes something in the application, it warns him when he tries to leave page or refresh it, that there are unsaved data.
But I also have a select which reloads the page when changed. If there are unsaved changes, alert pops up and warns the user. 
How to listen on the "event" when user cancels this warning popup? I need to do some cleanup in that scenario but don't know how to hook callback to it.

Answer (score 0):

I depends on the pop-up you're using, you could probably bind to an event on that pop-up something like @cancel / @close, take a look at the component.

Comment: I'm using the default browser alert for onbeforeunload event.

Comment: you could use confirm to capture the result, take a look at this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm